# Erratic behavior trying to reorder array via Drag and Drop in Vue 3 using vue-draggable-next

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuedraggable

I'm having trouble rearranging an array using vue-draggable-next to drag and drop items in an array. The array is objects containing song sections, (for example: "Verse 1", "Chorus", and "Bridge". When trying to rearrange them, after letting go of the drag, they seem to just go in whatever order they like. It appears to be random.  I'm hoping this is something stupid that I'm overlooking but I've come to the end of my knowledge.

I'm not sure if it's better practice to paste the entire component or simply the relevant parts so I'll do both below and any help is greatly appreciated.

The relevant section (HTML):

```
<draggable
          class="flex gap-2 w-full h-8"
          itemKey="id"
          v-model="arrangement.sections"
          tag="ul"
          @drop="handleDrop($event, arrangement)"
          group="sections"
          @change="logChange"
          :animation="300">
          <template #item="{ element: section }">
            <li class="text-xs p-2 bg-primary-500 text-white rounded-lg">
              {{ section.title }}
            </li>
          </template>
          <template #empty>
            <li class="h-full flex items-center justify-center opacity-50">
              <div class="flex gap-2 items-center">
                <span class="material-icons text-xs">add</span>
                <span class="text-xs">Add a section</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </template>
        </draggable>
```

The relevant section (script setup):

```
const handleDrop = (event, arrangement) => {
    const index = arrangement.sections.indexOf(draggedSection.value);
    if (index > -1) {
      arrangement.sections.splice(index, 1);
      arrangement.sections.splice(event.newIndex, 0, draggedSection.value);
    } else {
      arrangement.sections.splice(event.newIndex, 0, draggedSection.value);
    }
    store.dispatch("updateSong", song);
  };
  const logChange = () => {
    store.dispatch("updateSong", song);
  };
```

The entire component:

```
<template>
  <!-- Song Header -->
  <div
    class="flex h-20 bg-white border-b border-gray-300 items-center justify-between px-10">
    <h1>Arrangement</h1>
    <div class="flex">
      <button
        @click="chartSong()"
        class="btn-md btn-white btn-l btn-group w-fit">
        Charting
      </button>
      <button class="btn-md btn-primary btn-r btn-group w-fit">
        Arrangement
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-gray-50 min-h-[calc(100vh-204px)] p-2 md:p-6">
    <!-- Song Card -->
    <div
      class="max-w-7xl flex flex-col mx-auto p-6 w-fill border border-gray-300 md:rounded-lg shadow bg-white">
      <div class="flex w-full justify-between">
        <div class="flex items-center w-fill">
          <img
            v-if="!song.artURL"
            class="w-24 h-24 rounded border border-gray-300"
            src="../assets/Album Art/PlaceholderCover.png"
            alt="Album Art" />
          <img
            v-if="song.artURL"
            class="w-24 h-24 rounded border border-gray-300"
            :src="song.artURL"
            alt="Album Art" />
          <div class="flex flex-col justify-between ml-4">
            <div class="flex flex-col gap-2">
              <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900 leading-none">
                {{ song.title }}
              </h1>
              <h3 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-500 leading-none">
                {{ song.artist }}
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center">
          <div
            class="md:flex hidden gap-12 text-sm bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg p-4">
            <div>
              <div class="font-medium text-gray-500">Default Key</div>
              <div class="font-medium text-gray-900">{{ song.key }}</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="font-medium text-gray-500">Tempo (BPM)</div>
              <div class="font-medium text-gray-900">{{ song.tempo }}</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div class="font-medium text-gray-500">Time Signature</div>
              <div class="font-medium text-gray-900">{{ song.signature }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
            class="border h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center border-gray-300 rounded-lg ml-4 p-1"
            @click.prevent="openEditModal">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke-width="1.5"
              stroke="currentcolor"
              class="text-gray-500 w-5 h-5">
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M16.862 4.487l1.687-1.688a1.875 1.875 0 112.652 2.652L10.582 16.07a4.5 4.5 0 01-1.897 1.13L6 18l.8-2.685a4.5 4.5 0 011.13-1.897l8.932-8.931zm0 0L19.5 7.125M18 14v4.75A2.25 2.25 0 0115.75 21H5.25A2.25 2.25 0 013 18.75V8.25A2.25 2.25 0 015.25 6H10" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="flex gap-2 w-fill bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 p-2 mt-4 items-center">
        <span class="font-medium">Sections:</span>
        <draggable
          class="flex gap-2 w-full"
          itemKey="id"
          v-model="song.sections"
          tag="ul"
          @start="handleDragStart"
          :group="{ name: 'sections', pull: false, put: false }"
          :animation="300">
          <template #item="{ element: section }">
            <li class="text-xs p-2 bg-primary-500 text-white rounded-lg">
              {{ section.title }}
            </li>
          </template>
        </draggable>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Song Details Mobile -->
    <div
      class="flex md:hidden justify-around px-6 text-sm bg-gray-50 border-b border-gray-300 border-x rounded-b-lg">
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <div class="font-medium text-gray-500">Default Key</div>
        <div class="font-medium text-gray-900">{{ song.key }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <div class="font-medium text-gray-500">Tempo (BPM)</div>
        <div class="font-medium text-gray-900">{{ song.tempo }}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
        <div class="font-medium text-gray-500">Time Signature</div>
        <div class="font-medium text-gray-900">{{ song.signature }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arrangement -->
    <div
      v-for="arrangement in arrangements"
      class="items-center mt-6 max-w-7xl flex flex-col mx-auto p-6 w-full border border-gray-300 md:rounded-lg shadow bg-white">
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center w-full mb-4">
        <div v-if="!editArrangeTitle" class="text-xl font-medium">
          {{ arrangement.title }}
        </div>
        <input
          v-if="editArrangeTitle"
          v-model="arrangement.title"
          class="text-xl border border-gray-300 -m-[1px] rounded-lg font-medium" />
        <div class="flex gap-4">
          <button
            v-if="!editArrangeTitle"
            @click.prevent="toggleEditArrangeTitle()"
            class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-600">
            edit
          </button>
          <button
            v-if="editArrangeTitle"
            @click.prevent="toggleEditArrangeTitle(), saveTitle()"
            class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-600">
            save
          </button>
          <button
            @click.prevent="deleteArrangement(arrangement)"
            class="btn-square-md btn-white text-destructive-500 hover:text-destructive-500 active:text-destructive-500">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke-width="1.5"
              stroke="currentColor"
              class="w-6 h-6">
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                d="M14.74 9l-.346 9m-4.788 0L9.26 9m9.968-3.21c.342.052.682.107 1.022.166m-1.022-.165L18.16 19.673a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244 2.077H8.084a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244-2.077L4.772 5.79m14.456 0a48.108 48.108 0 00-3.478-.397m-12 .562c.34-.059.68-.114 1.022-.165m0 0a48.11 48.11 0 013.478-.397m7.5 0v-.916c0-1.18-.91-2.164-2.09-2.201a51.964 51.964 0 00-3.32 0c-1.18.037-2.09 1.022-2.09 2.201v.916m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        class="w-full p-2 flex gap-2 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 items-center">
        <span class="font-medium">Sections:</span>
        <draggable
          class="flex gap-2 w-full h-8"
          itemKey="id"
          v-model="arrangement.sections"
          tag="ul"
          @drop="handleDrop($event, arrangement)"
          group="sections"
          @change="logChange"
          :animation="300">
          <template #item="{ element: section }">
            <li class="text-xs p-2 bg-primary-500 text-white rounded-lg">
              {{ section.title }}
            </li>
          </template>
          <template #empty>
            <li class="h-full flex items-center justify-center opacity-50">
              <div class="flex gap-2 items-center">
                <span class="material-icons text-xs">add</span>
                <span class="text-xs">Add a section</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </template>
        </draggable>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrangement -->
    <div class="flex justify-center mt-6">
      <button
        class="max-w-7xl items-center border w-full h-[148px] font-medium text-primary-600 rounded-lg border-dashed border-gray-300"
        @click="addArrangement()">
        Add Arrangement
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="bg-gray-50 w-full sticky bottom-0">
    <div
      class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-6 py-2 w-full md:flex md:items-center md:justify-between lg:px-8">
      <div class="flex justify-center space-x-6 md:order-2">
        <a
          v-for="item in navigation"
          :key="item.name"
          :href="item.href"
          class="text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500">
          <span class="sr-only">{{ item.name }}</span>
          <component :is="item.icon" class="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-8 md:order-1 md:mt-0">
        <p class="text-center text-xs leading-5 text-gray-500">
          &copy; 2023 SongChart, LLC. All rights reserved.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { defineComponent, h } from "vue";
  import { useStore } from "vuex";
  import { useRouter, useRoute } from "vue-router";
  import { computed, ref, watch } from "vue";
  import { PlusCircleIcon, TrashIcon } from "@heroicons/vue/20/solid";
  import EditSong from "@/components/EditSong.vue";
  import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
  import draggable from "vuedraggable";

  // Variables
  const route = useRoute();
  const router = useRouter();
  const store = useStore();
  const song = store.getters.getSongById(route.params.id);
  const editSong = ref(false);
  const currentSong = computed(() => song);
  const sections = computed(() => song.sections);
  const arrangements = computed(() => song.arrangements || []);
  let draggedSection = ref(null);
  const editArrangeTitle = ref(false);

  // Methods
  const toggleEditArrangeTitle = () => {
    editArrangeTitle.value = !editArrangeTitle.value;
  };
  const chartSong = () => {
    router.push(`/songs/${song.id}`);
  };
  const addArrangement = async () => {
    const newArrangement = {
      title: "New Arrangement",
      sections: [],
      id: uuidv4(),
    };
    song.arrangements.push(newArrangement);
    await store.dispatch("updateSong", song);
  };
  const deleteArrangement = async (arrangement) => {
    const index = song.arrangements.indexOf(arrangement);
    song.arrangements.splice(index, 1);
    await store.dispatch("updateSong", song);
  };
  const saveTitle = async () => {
    await store.dispatch("updateSong", song);
  };
  const handleDragStart = (section) => {
    console.log("section.item is: ", section.item._underlying_vm_);
    draggedSection.value = {
      title: section.item._underlying_vm_.title,
      id: uuidv4(),
      content: section.item._underlying_vm_.content,
      inputText: section.item._underlying_vm_.inputText,
      notes: section.item._underlying_vm_.notes,
      tempTitle: section.item._underlying_vm_.title,
      type: section.item._underlying_vm_.type,
    };
    console.log(draggedSection.value);
  };
  //Check if the section exists in the list and if it does, simply update the index, if it does not, add it to the array and set the index to the position where it's being dragged, then update the song
  const handleDrop = (event, arrangement) => {
    const index = arrangement.sections.indexOf(draggedSection.value);
    if (index > -1) {
      arrangement.sections.splice(index, 1);
      arrangement.sections.splice(event.newIndex, 0, draggedSection.value);
    } else {
      arrangement.sections.splice(event.newIndex, 0, draggedSection.value);
    }
    store.dispatch("updateSong", song);
  };
  const logChange = () => {
    store.dispatch("updateSong", song);
  };

  // Navigation
  const navigation = [
    {
      name: "Facebook",
      href: "#",
      icon: defineComponent({
        render: () =>
          h("svg", { fill: "currentColor", viewBox: "0 0 24 24" }, [
            h("path", {
              "fill-rule": "evenodd",
              d: "M22 12c0-5.523-4.477-10-10-10S2 6.477 2 12c0 4.991 3.657 9.128 8.438 9.878v-6.987h-2.54V12h2.54V9.797c0-2.506 1.492-3.89 3.777-3.89 1.094 0 2.238.195 2.238.195v2.46h-1.26c-1.243 0-1.63.771-1.63 1.562V12h2.773l-.443 2.89h-2.33v6.988C18.343 21.128 22 16.991 22 12z",
              "clip-rule": "evenodd",
            }),
          ]),
      }),
    },
    {
      name: "Instagram",
      href: "#",
      icon: defineComponent({
        render: () =>
          h("svg", { fill: "currentColor", viewBox: "0 0 24 24" }, [
            h("path", {
              "fill-rule": "evenodd",
              d: "M12.315 2c2.43 0 2.784.013 3.808.06 1.064.049 1.791.218 2.427.465a4.902 4.902 0 011.772 1.153 4.902 4.902 0 011.153 1.772c.247.636.416 1.363.465 2.427.048 1.067.06 1.407.06 4.123v.08c0 2.643-.012 2.987-.06 4.043-.049 1.064-.218 1.791-.465 2.427a4.902 4.902 0 01-1.153 1.772 4.902 4.902 0 01-1.772 1.153c-.636.247-1.363.416-2.427.465-1.067.048-1.407.06-4.123.06h-.08c-2.643 0-2.987-.012-4.043-.06-1.064-.049-1.791-.218-2.427-.465a4.902 4.902 0 01-1.772-1.153 4.902 4.902 0 01-1.153-1.772c-.247-.636-.416-1.363-.465-2.427-.047-1.024-.06-1.379-.06-3.808v-.63c0-2.43.013-2.784.06-3.808.049-1.064.218-1.791.465-2.427a4.902 4.902 0 011.153-1.772A4.902 4.902 0 015.45 2.525c.636-.247 1.363-.416 2.427-.465C8.901 2.013 9.256 2 11.685 2h.63zm-.081 1.802h-.468c-2.456 0-2.784.011-3.807.058-.975.045-1.504.207-1.857.344-.467.182-.8.398-1.15.748-.35.35-.566.683-.748 1.15-.137.353-.3.882-.344 1.857-.047 1.023-.058 1.351-.058 3.807v.468c0 2.456.011 2.784.058 3.807.045.975.207 1.504.344 1.857.182.466.399.8.748 1.15.35.35.683.566 1.15.748.353.137.882.3 1.857.344 1.054.048 1.37.058 4.041.058h.08c2.597 0 2.917-.01 3.96-.058.976-.045 1.505-.207 1.858-.344.466-.182.8-.398 1.15-.748.35-.35.566-.683.748-1.15.137-.353.3-.882.344-1.857.048-1.055.058-1.37.058-4.041v-.08c0-2.597-.01-2.917-.058-3.96-.045-.976-.207-1.505-.344-1.858a3.097 3.097 0 00-.748-1.15 3.098 3.098 0 00-1.15-.748c-.353-.137-.882-.3-1.857-.344-1.023-.047-1.351-.058-3.807-.058zM12 6.865a5.135 5.135 0 110 10.27 5.135 5.135 0 010-10.27zm0 1.802a3.333 3.333 0 100 6.666 3.333 3.333 0 000-6.666zm5.338-3.205a1.2 1.2 0 110 2.4 1.2 1.2 0 010-2.4z",
              "clip-rule": "evenodd",
            }),
          ]),
      }),
    },
    {
      name: "Twitter",
      href: "#",
      icon: defineComponent({
        render: () =>
          h("svg", { fill: "currentColor", viewBox: "0 0 24 24" }, [
            h("path", {
              d: "M18.244 2.25h3.308l-7.227 8.26 8.502 11.24H16.17l-5.214-6.817L4.99 21.75H1.68l7.73-8.835L1.254 2.25H8.08l4.713 6.231zm-1.161 17.52h1.833L7.084 4.126H5.117z",
            }),
          ]),
      }),
    },
    {
      name: "YouTube",
      href: "#",
      icon: defineComponent({
        render: () =>
          h("svg", { fill: "currentColor", viewBox: "0 0 24 24" }, [
            h("path", {
              "fill-rule": "evenodd",
              d: "M19.812 5.418c.861.23 1.538.907 1.768 1.768C21.998 8.746 22 12 22 12s0 3.255-.418 4.814a2.504 2.504 0 0 1-1.768 1.768c-1.56.419-7.814.419-7.814.419s-6.255 0-7.814-.419a2.505 2.505 0 0 1-1.768-1.768C2 15.255 2 12 2 12s0-3.255.417-4.814a2.507 2.507 0 0 1 1.768-1.768C5.744 5 11.998 5 11.998 5s6.255 0 7.814.418ZM15.194 12 10 15V9l5.194 3Z",
              "clip-rule": "evenodd",
            }),
          ]),
      }),
    },
  ];
</script>
```

I've searched google, asked GitHub copilot and even had chatGPT take a look at the code with no help. I've felt like I've had a pretty good grasp on this entire project until I got to the drag and drop stuff, and that's where my experience is limited and knowledge follows. :P